# N-coinvariants of $\mathcal{C}^{sm}_c(N,A)$ (compactly supported smooth functions on $N$) ?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hello,

I am trying to compute a space of co-invariants.

$N$ is the subgroup of $GL_2(Q_p)$ of upper triangular matrices with $1$'s on the diagonal

$E$ is a finite extension of $Q_p$, with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_E$ and uniformizer $\varpi_E$, and $A$ is an artinian ring of the form : $\mathcal{O}_E / \varpi_E^n \mathcal{O}_E$.

I am considering the space $\mathcal{C}^{sm}_c(N,A)$ of compactly supported smooth functions on $N$, with the action of $N$ by right translation.

My problem is to show that $\mathcal{C}^{sm}_c(N,A)_N = 0$ (the space of coinvariants).

As I am not familiar with coinvariant computations I don't see how to show it.
Any idea (or reference maybe) ?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a random thought, just off the top of my head. You're looking for a translation-invariant linear functional $\phi$ on $C^{sm}_c(N, A)$. Let $N_0$ be an open compact. By restriction, $\phi$ defines a linear functional on $C^{sm}(N_0, A)$, which is evidently $N_0$-invariant. Now $C^{sm}(N_0, A)$ is just the reduction modulo $\varpi^n$ of $C^{cts}(N_0, \mathcal{O}_E)$, and the continuous linear functionals on this are the Iwasawa algebra of $N_0$, which is a rather nice and explicit ring. By doing this, perhaps you can show that the restriction of $\phi$ to $C^{sm}(N_0, A)$ is zero?

Comment: ... And if this works, then you are done, since any compact subset of $N$ is contained in a compact open subgroup.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
But I am not sure to understand it...
Why would I look for a translation-invariant linear functional ?
Maybe my question is a bit messy, I'll try to rewrite it properly.

Comment: An $N$-invariant linear functional is the same as a linear functional that factors through the coinvariants.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is just a detailed version of David Loeffler's comment.

First of all, I would observe that $N\cong \mathbb{Q}_p$ via
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&a\\
0&1
\end{array}\right)\mapsto a
$$
Moreover, since you look at compactly supported functions, each of them is in $\mathcal{C}^{sm}(p^{-k}\mathbb{Z_p},A)$ for some $k$, so $\mathcal{C}_c^{sm}(N,A)\cong\varinjlim_k\mathcal{C}^{sm}(p^{-k}\mathbb{Z}_p,A)$. Since injective limits commute with (almost everything and, in particular) homology, we are reduced to show
$$
\mathcal{C}^{sm}(\mathbb{Z}_p,A)_{p^k\mathbb{Z}_p}=0
$$
If we were considering simply the functions $\mathrm{Map}(\mathbb{Z}_p,A)$, the object in our hands would be $A[\mathbb{Z}_p]$. But you insist that your functions be *smooth* so in particular continuous which implies (and is hence equivalent) to being locally constant because $A$ is discrete. A locally constant function from $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to $A$ factors through $p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some $n$ so we find
$$
\mathcal{C}^{sm}(\mathbb{Z}_p,A)=\varprojlim_nA[\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}]\cong A[[T]]
$$
where the last isomorphism comes from sending a topological generator of the projective limit (like $(1,1,1,\dots)$) to $(1+T)$ (this is the Iwasawa algebra David was referring to). Keeping track of the action we see that it becomes multiplication by $(1+T)$, and the coinvariants with respect to $p^k\mathbb{Z}_p$ which we are looking for are the quotient $A[[T]]/(1+T)^k$ which vanishes because $(1+T)$ is a unit in the power series algebra.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I agree that we only have to show that
$$\mathcal{C}^{sm}(\mathbb{Z}_p,A)_{\mathbb{Z}_p} = 0$$
but I do not see the isomorphism
$$\mathcal{C}^{sm}(\mathbb{Z}_p,A) = \varprojlim A[\mathbb{Z}_p/p^n \mathbb{Z}_p]$$
Moreover the Iwasawa algebra of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ over $A$ is the continuous dual of $\mathcal{C}^{sm}(\mathbb{Z}_p,A)$ (as David said) but why this latter should be isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}^{sm}(\mathbb{Z}_p,A)$ ?...